# Strange DNS entries on a macbook pro

Tags: dns

I was trying to add an entry in `/etc/hosts` on a MacBook Pro 2018 (macOS 10.14.1) that has been installed transferring data from another MacBook Pro (2013 running macOS 10.13.6) when I found the following entries (beside the normal ones):

`54.170.1.113 pgvmb
54.217.124.67 pgvmc
54.170.13.116 pgvma`

I can't remember edited `/etc/hosts` on the old MacBook Pro, but sure I did not edit on the new MacBook Pro.

The ip addresses seems to be pointing to Dublin addresses (and I never accessed a Dublin address) and they are not present on a Mac mini that I was able to access (I can't access the previous MacBook Pro to check `/etc/hosts`)

Does anyone know something about these entries?

Answer (score 2):

I would save a copy and delete those entries or the entire hosts file. You are correct to try and trace the IP address, but there is no good reason to maintain undesired overrides. You can watch for these changes to come back if you think some software is performing the edits.